# F# - Return element from sequence

Tags: f#, seq

Spoiler-Alert! You'll see a solution for projecteuler.net-Problem 7.

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but I could not find a question here asking the same.

I compute a sequence of numbers in a function and want to return the nth number.

```
let isPrime x = 
    {2..x/2}
    |> Seq.exists (fun e -> x%e=0)
    |> not

let PrimeNumber nth = 
    let unfolder a =
        a
        |> Seq.unfold (fun e -> Some(e, e+1))
        |> Seq.find isPrime
        |> fun e -> Some(e, e)

    2
    |> Seq.unfold unfolder
    |> Seq.skip (nth-1) 
    |> Seq.head

let ans = PrimeNumber 10001
```

`ans` will always be 2, but why?

When I evaluate the last expression in `PrimeNumber` with `nth=10001` then the correct item is returned. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in your use of Seq.find.

Seq.find, from the documentation, returns the *first* element for which the condition is true. In this case, that is 2.

Therefore, your unfolder expression will simply generate an infinite sequence of 2s, so whatever element you take, it will always be a 2.

To see this, run just this snippet of your code:

```
2
|> Seq.unfold unfolder

//output: val it : seq<int> = seq [2; 2; 2; 2; ...]
```

Comment: Changing `|> fun e -> Some(e, e)` to `|> fun e -> Some(e, e+1)` fixed it. Thanks for the hint. After restarting visual studio it didn't evaluate to the right solution. I don't know why it worked before.

Comment: @Micha90 : Reconsider `e+1` – that will test every even number pointlessly.

Comment: What do you suggest? e+2 skips 3 as a prime when I start with 2. Also it yields the wrong solution, the nth+1 prime number. And it doesn't run faster, but I can't see why. I expected it to run ~twice as fast.

Comment: @Micha90 : Start with 3 and manually inject `2` into the head of your sequence; e.g. `2 |> Seq.unfold unfolder |> Seq.skip (nth-1)` becomes `3 |> Seq.unfold unfolder |> Seq.append (Seq.singleton 2) |> Seq.skip (nth-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

You want Seq.filter if you need to stick to this solution:

```
let isPrime x = 
{2..x/2}
|> Seq.exists (fun e -> x%e=0)
|> not

let PrimeNumber nth = 
    let unfolder a =
       a
       |> Seq.unfold (fun e -> Some(e, e+1))
       |> Seq.filter isPrime

    2
    |> unfolder
    |> Seq.skip (nth-1) 
    |> Seq.item 0
```

`let ans = PrimeNumber 100` will give you 541
But as eluded to in the comments that are other more efficient solutions.